# LinearRegression on black friday data set with anaconda

Tags: python, dataset, anaconda, linear-regression

im trying to Predict purchase amount using anaconda  with black friday data set 
this is my code

```
    train=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\data sets\\train.csv")
    test=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\data sets\\test.csv")
    import numpy as np
    frames=[train,test]
    data=pd.concat(frames)
    print(data.shape)
    data.head()
    data.isnull().any()
    data.fillna(999,inplace=True)
    data.head(20)
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="0-17"]="15"
    data["Age"].head(10)
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="18-25"]="21"
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="26-35"]="30"
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="36-45"]="40"
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="46-50"]="48"
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="51-55"]="53"
    data.Age[data["Age"]=="55+"]="60"
   data.Stay_In_Current_City_Years[data["Stay_In_Current_City_Years"]=="4+"]
   ="4"
   data["Age"]=data["Age"].astype(int)
   data["Stay_In_Current_City_Years"]=data["Stay_In_Current_City_Years"].
   astype(int)
   data.dtypes
   data["Marital_Status"]=data["Marital_Status"].astype(int)
   data["Occupation"]=data["Occupation"].astype(int)
   data["Product_Category_1"]=data["Product_Category_1"].astype(int)
   data["Product_Category_1"]=data["Product_Category_1"].astype(int)
   data["Product_Category_2"]=data["Product_Category_2"].astype(float)
   data["Product_Category_3"]=data["Product_Category_3"].astype(float)
   data["Purchase"]=data["Purchase"].astype(float)
   sex=pd.get_dummies(data["Gender"]).iloc[:,1:]
   data1=pd.concat([data,sex],axis=1)
   city=pd.get_dummies(data["City_Category"]).iloc[:,1:]
   data1=pd.concat([data,sex,city],axis=1)
   # cross validation and creating the features and the target variable 
   from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
   y=data1["Purchase"]
   x=data1[["Age","City_Category","Gender","Marital_Status","Occupation",
 "Product_Category_1","Product_Category_2","Product_Category_3","Product_ID"
  ,"Stay_In_Current_City_Years","User_ID","M","B","C"]]
  x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y)
   # building the regration
   from sklearn import linear_model
   reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
   reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

but i keep on getting this :

```
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'P00100642'
```

what does it mean? are there any more features i need to convert to integers in order to run the regression?
 and how can i fix it ?
thanks :)

Comment: Which line of your code is giving the error?

Comment: I'd say it's some of your `astype(float)` which is giving you the error, so you better check what's the data you're trying to convert, why you'd expect it to be float (i.e. string representing a float) and why it's not what you expect...

Comment: this line:  reg.fit(x_train,y_train)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine learning algorithms take only numeric data. The column `Purchase_ID` doesn't have numeric data as it starts with '**P**'. You are trying to pass it as it is hence getting the error.

Notice the pattern in the values and you'll see every entry starts with '`P00`'. As it is a string, hence you can replace it with *nothing*.

Try this:

```
data['Product_ID'] = data['Product_ID'].str.replace('P00', '')
```

After that, you can scale down the values using `StandardScaler`.